Prove independence of variables & find distribution
I’m struggling with the following question
$$ X = A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta$$
$$Y= B\cos\theta - A\sin\theta$$
Where $A,B\sim N(0,1)$ (A and B are independent) and $\theta$ is a constant
Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and find the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ (which I believe to be $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$)
My (conflicted) ideas:
I thought the sum of normal distributions was normal, and that working out $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ would suffice but that seems too simple so I was thinking about doing
$$P(X=x)=\int _{-\infty}^xP(A\cos\theta=a)P(B\sin\theta=x-a)\ da $$
But based on other examples I feel like I should try a similar expression but for $P(X<x)$ instead (I’m also not entirely sure why that’s done in other cases, so I’m not sure if it applies here).
I’ve seen a similar question for the first part that considered $CoV(X,Y)$ and used a theorem about sums of normal variables with $Cov=0$ to show they’re independent. I don’t I’ve covered that theorem yet, and was wondering if it was achievable without.

Squaring and adding gives $X^2+Y^2=A^2+B^2$. I'm not that well versed with probability though, so if I tell something wrong please tell me. I'll delete this comment

An easy solution to this can be given using characteristic functions.

Assume $A$ and $B$ are standard normals, with a joint normal distribution. (You don't state whether $A$ and $B$ are to be independent.)
They then have covariance $\rho:=E(AB)$. The pair $(X,Y)$ (being a linear transformation of $(A,B)$) is then also jointly normally distributed, with means both $0$, variances both $1+\rho\sin(\theta)$. $X$ and $Y$ will be independent if and only if their covariance $E(XY)$ is $0$. Can you express $E(XY)$ in terms of $\rho$ and $\theta$? This is easiest when $A$ and $B$ are independent; that is, when $\rho=0$.

A and B are independent, I completely forgot, I’ll add it in now. How do we know X and Y will be independent if their covariance is 0?

@edster101 they're jointly normal...
